# XMLHttpRequest status between firefox and chrome

Tags: xmlhttprequest

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                createPopup(this);
            }
            else if (this.status == 404) {
                alert("file not found from load");
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

Hi, I am learning about html and css and now javaScript with Dom.
I am trying to parse xml file and know that I have to use XMLHttpRequest to get the data.

To make exception handling such as "there is no file", "xml has fault(wrong xml)", I am trying to use the XMLHttpRequest's member variables "readyStatus", "status" to figure out what status of the result.
If there is another way to deal with this problem, let me know..

First, the chrome doesn't give the "status" value whereas the firefox give with same code. but it is limited to give status == 200 when the file exist regardless of file's status(wrong or not), do you know why?

Second, How can I see "status == 404" using status, could you tell me when it occur?

Comment: I got to know when I upload it to one domain I use, they give me the 404 error too. but locally it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/" ... This appear in the alert of the Chrome Console...I have the same problem...